# Como hacer de que el usuario acceda a determinadas rutas solo cuando este logueado?

Tags: javascript, express, jwt, auth, jsonwebtoken

Realicé un login con google que funciona y anda perfecto. El cual, cuando se completa el inicio de sesión, me devuelve un jwt que almaceno por localStorage.

```
const data = {id_token};

fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(({jwt}) => {

      if (jwt) {
        localStorage.setItem('x-token', jwt);
      }


  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
```

Mi problema es que como hago para que el usuario solo pueda acceder a determinadas rutas cuando tenga ese token y sea verdadero? Puesto que podría almacenar cualquier dato aleatorio en la variable "x-token" del localStorage del navegador y tener acceso a cualquier ruta.

En postman me funciona la validación del token y los usuarios pueden acceder a determinadas rutas cuando solo lo ponen en el req.header. Ahora bien como hago para imitar lo mismo pero en el navegador?

```
const validateJwt = (req, res, next) => {

let token = req.header('x-token')

//If the header is not empty, then validate the header and the token.
if (!token) {
    res.status(400).json({
        msg: 'Token doesn´t exists'
    })

}else{

    jsonwebtoken.verify(token, process.env.SECRETORPRIVATEKEY, (err, decoded) => {

        if (err) {
            res.status(403).json({
                msg: 'Token no valid'
            })

        }else{
            next();
        }

    });    
     
}}
```

Comment: El tema , si entendí bien, se resuelve en el router de express, si no está logueado lo rediriges a otro lado, `if ( // no logueado) { res.redirect('/login') }`

Comment: Claro, eso lo entiendo. Pero como se si está logueado o no? Yo desde el backend envio el login (jwt) al frontend, pero en el frontend, como lo consulto y verifico cada vez que quiera acceder a una ruta?

Comment: Bueno, eso tiene que ver con si guardas un estado o no,  según entiendo el token lo guardas en el navegador del cliente, de esa manera lo tienes que mandar siempre en cada request que hace el frontend y validar siempre en el  backend.

Comment: A ver, el flujo puede ser de muchas maneras, una forma común con lo que estás haciendo es usando el protcolo  OAuth 2.0 mira esta imágen https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CPbvxxslDTU/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: Ahhhh claro. Cada vez que acceda a una ruta debería verificarlo con un fetch?

Comment: Generalmente se guarda el token en el backend, en una base de datos por ejemplo, y solo se valida el token, cuando expira ese token lo tienes que borrar o invalidar. Ese token puede estar asociado a un usuario y a los recursos a los que puede acceder por ejemplo. De esta manera el frontend siempre manda el token y el backen siempre lo valida. Cuando expira lo puedes redirigir de  manera que se loguee nuevamente y genere otro token.

Comment: Con esa imagen entendí absolutamente todo. Claro, cada vez que acceda a una ruta que se necesite estar loguedo tengo que hacer una petición al backend verificando si el token es correcto o no. Mil gracias por la ayuda, en unos minutos posteo la solución. Saludos!